# I want to update an article every 5 minutes with javascript, can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I'm have been trying to get a single article on my website and have it swtich to another article on interval. I'm using flask to scrape the arcile title,image and text from 3 different source. Then I render a template with those elements in a list.

See code:

```
@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
offshorenergyfeed = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.feedburner.com/OffshoreEnergyToday?format=xml')
offshorewindfeed = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/OffshoreWindNews?format=xml')
rechargefeed = feedparser.parse('http://www.rechargenews.com/rss/')
feedlinks = [offshorenergyfeed.entries[0]['link'],offshorewindfeed.entries[0]['link'],rechargefeed.entries[0]['link']]
artikel_tekst = []
artikel_titel = []
artikel_image = []
for link in feedlinks:
    artikel = Article(link)
    artikel.download()
    artikel.parse()
    artikel_tekst.append(artikel.text)
    artikel_titel.append(artikel.title)
    artikel_image.append(artikel.top_image)


return render_template('graph.html',
artikel_tekst = artikel_tekst,
artikel_titel = artikel_titel,
artikel_image = artikel_image,
)
```

Now I want to I want to display 1 article at the time and swtich it to another with an interval(lets say 5 minutes). For some reason I can only get it to work with the title switch. Text and Image won't switch with the given code:

```
  <div id=newsarticle_container>
     <h1 id='titel'>{{artikel_titel[0]}}</h1>
     <img id=plaatje src="{{artikel_image[0]}}">
     <div id='tekst'>{{artikel_tekst[0]}}</div>
 </div>
  <script>
var titles = ["{{artikel_titel[0]}}", "{{artikel_titel[1]}}", "{{artikel_titel[2]}}"];
var images = ["{{artikel_image[0]}}", "{{artikel_image[1]}}", "{{artikel_image[2]}}"];
var text = ["{{artikel_tekst[0]}}", "{{artikel_tekst[1]}}", "{{artikel_tekst[2]}}"];
var counter = 0;
var elem1 = document.getElementById("titel");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("plaatje");
var elem3 = document.getElementById("plaatje");
var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
  elem1.innerHTML = titles[counter];
  elem2.innerHTML = images[counter];
  elem3.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= titles.length) {
    counter = 0;

  }
}

 </script>
```

Can someone please help me out. I have been struggeling on this for a long time. I think i'm close to the solution but maybe it's needs to be way different. Let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
<h1 id='titel'>{{artikel_titel[0]}}</h1>
 <img id=plaatje src="{{artikel_image[0]}}">
 <div id='tekst'>{{artikel_tekst[0]}}</div>
```

which should be

```
<h1 id='titel'>{{artikel_titel[0]}}</h1>
 <img id='plaatje' src="{{artikel_image[0]}}">
 <div id='tekst'>{{artikel_tekst[0]}}</div>
```

later in your code you have

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("titel");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("plaatje");
var elem3 = document.getElementById("plaatje");
```

which should be changed to

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("titel");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("plaatje");
var elem3 = document.getElementById("text");
```

Comment: Sorry that were just some typo's . But that still doesn't make the function work.

Comment: maybe you have more typo's in your code, or din't you post the code you are actually using?

Comment: This is the code i'm using. It's only not working. I don't think it are typo's. I tried retyping the code over and over again with a different syntax. I doesn't seem to work

Comment: you should check which errors you are getting in f12 ->console it can tell if it is your script or something else